# Duplicating a function containing static variables in memory

Tags: c, memory, function-pointers

I'm messing with function pointers and what I'm trying to do is to duplicate a function in memory, so for that I'm using `mmap` to be able to execute my memory, then `memcpy` to copy the function in my new pointer, what I want to acheive by doing that is to create a new instance of the static variable inside of my function. The thing is I did something wrong when copying the function, because when I try to call the function, it segfaults. Here is the code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int     g_pagesize;

void    foo(void)
{
    static int i = 0;

    i++;
    printf("%d\n", i);
}

void    bar(void)
{
    printf("some stuff\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    void    (*fp1)(void), (*fp2)(void);

    g_pagesize = getpagesize();
    fp1 = mmap(NULL, g_pagesize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    fp2 = mmap(NULL, g_pagesize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    memcpy(fp1, foo, bar - foo);
    memcpy(fp2, foo, bar - foo);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        (*fp1)();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        (*fp2)();
    return (0);
}

/*
** Wanted output:
** 1
** 2
** 3
** 4
** 5
** 1
** 2
** 3
** 4
** 5
*/
```

Comment: Static variables aren't stored in the function code. They're in the data segment, and the function contains the address. This memory is allocated by the compiler, and copying the function won't duplicate it.

Comment: That's what I thought but I wanted to try to mess up with that because I saw it was possible to store function in heap, but if the function doesn't contain the variable that explains

Comment: @KamilCuk Isn't the next function in the file aligned next ?

Comment: It will not work. The static data is not in the code segment. Functions do not have to be placed in the order they are defined in the source code.

Comment: If you want to have many instanced of the code simple use the language which allows it - for example C++. If you want objects use OO language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the comments this won't work, as there is only one instance of the `i` variable, stored in the [`.bss` segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss) which is the case for all `static` variables. Thus, even if the code for `foo` were to be copied in such a way that it could run without causing a segmentation fault, it would simply increment from 1 through 10.

The more interesting part of this question are those segmentation faults, and why they occur.

To consider what's happening, let's look at some (relatively unoptimised) x86-64 assembly output for the `foo` function, with the original source interleaved:

```
00000000000011c9 <foo>:
# void    foo(void)
# {
    11c9:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64
    11cd:       55                      push   rbp
    11ce:       48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
#     static int i = 0;
#
#     i++;
    11d1:       8b 05 3d 2e 00 00       mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rip+0x2e3d]        # 4014 <i.3666>
    11d7:       83 c0 01                add    eax,0x1
    11da:       89 05 34 2e 00 00       mov    DWORD PTR [rip+0x2e34],eax        # 4014 <i.3666>
#     printf("%d\n", i);
    11e0:       8b 05 2e 2e 00 00       mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rip+0x2e2e]        # 4014 <i.3666>
    11e6:       89 c6                   mov    esi,eax
    11e8:       48 8d 3d 15 0e 00 00    lea    rdi,[rip+0xe15]        # 2004 <_IO_stdin_used+0x4>
    11ef:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x0
    11f4:       e8 b7 fe ff ff          call   10b0 <printf@plt>
# }
    11f9:       90                      nop
    11fa:       5d                      pop    rbp
    11fb:       c3                      ret
```

At address `0x11d1` the relative form of the [`MOV` instruction](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mov) is used to load the current value of `i` into the `eax` register. As you can see, the mnemonic is of the form:

```
mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rip+<offset>]
```

which can be read as:

- calculate an address based on the current instruction pointer (`rip`) plus the provided offset, then
- copy the 32 bit value (`DWORD`) stored there into the `eax` register

This offset value (`0x2e3d`) is calculated at compile time so that when the instruction is executed, `rip` is precisely `0x2e3d` less than the location in memory of the static `i` variable. When making a copy of `foo` in a dynamic location with `mmap` and `memcpy` as you have done, the copied offset remains the same, but the value of `rip` when that instruction is executed will be significantly different.

More importantly, the calculated address of `rip+0x2e3d` may end up in a region of memory not marked as available for the process, and accessing this address will cause the segmentation fault. Subsequent accesses at `0x11da` and `0x11e0` will cause the same issue.

Continuing on, even if you were to change the static variable `i` to a local stack variable, you would still run into issues, as at address `0x11f4` the relative form of the [`CALL` instruction](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/call) is used to invoke `printf`, with an offset of `0x10b0`, which will also cause a segmentation fault, for the same reason.

If you were able to rectify that, there is one more relative addressing calculation in the `foo` function, at address `0x11e8`, which uses the [`LEA` instruction](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/lea) to calculate the address of the `"%d\n"` format string. The calculation itself is fine, however any access of that calculated address will likely also cause a segmentation fault.

Comment: Thanks for your nice and well explained answer, I almost thought that I could do object-oriented programming in C using this method :( too bad it doesn't work